# Can PostgreSQL JOIN on jsonb array objects?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, lateral-join

I am considering switching to PostgreSQL, because of the JSON support. However, I am wondering, if the following would be possible with a single query:

Let's say there are two tables:

Table 1) organisations:

```
  ID (INT)  |  members (JSONB)                                        |
------------+---------------------------------------------------------|
     1      | [{ id: 23, role: "admin" }, { id: 24, role: "default" }]|
     2      | [{ id: 23, role: "user" }]
```

Table 2) users:

```
  ID (INT)  | name TEXT | email TEXT    |
------------+-----------+---------------|
     23     | Max       | max@gmail.com |
     24     | Joe       | joe@gmail.com |
```

Now I want to get a result like this (all i have is the ID of the organisation [1]):

```
  ID (INT)  |  members (JSONB)                                       |
------------+--------------------------------------------------------|
     1      | [{ id: 23, name: "Max", email: "max@gmail.com", role: 
                "admin" },
               { id: 24, name: "Joe", email: "joe@gmail.com ", role: 
                "default" }]
(1 row)
```

I know this is not what JSONB is intended for and that there is a better solution for storing this data in SQL, but I am just curious if it would be possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes it is possible to meet this requirement with Postgres. Here is a solution for 9.6 or higher.

```
SELECT o.id, JSON_AGG(
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'id'    , u.id, 
        'name'  , u.name, 
        'email' , u.email, 
        'role'  , e.usr->'role'
    )
)
FROM organisations o
CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(o.data) AS e(usr)
INNER JOIN users u ON (e.usr->'id')::text::int = u.id
GROUP BY o.id
```

See [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4a3026c505615dfc65e6c6582bed3cb0).

Explanation :

- the `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS` function splits the organisation json array into rows (one per user) ; it is usually used in combination with `JOIN LATERAL`
- to join the `users` table, we access the content of the `id` field using the `->` operator
- for each user, the `JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT` is used to create a new object, by passing a list of values/keys pairs ; most values comes from the `users` table, excepted the `role`, that is taken from the organisation json element
- the query aggregates by organisation id, using `JSONB_AGG` to generate a json array by combining above objects

For more information, you may also have a look at [Postgres JSON Functions documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE).

Comment: Is `INNER JOIN LATERAL JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(o.data) AS e(usr) ON TRUE` equivalent to `CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(o.data) AS e(usr)`?

Answer (score 1):

There might be more ways to do that. One way would use `jsonb_to_recordset()` to transform the JSON into a record set you can join. Then create a JSON from the result using `jsonb_build_object()` for the individual members and `jsonb_agg()` to aggregate them in a JSON array.

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', "u"."id",
                                    'name', "u"."name",
                                    'email', "u"."email",
                                    'role', "m"."role"))
       FROM "organisations" "o"
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(o."members") "m" ("id" integer,
                                                                    "role" text)
            INNER JOIN "users" "u"
                       ON "u"."id" = "m"."id";
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0166f8b11b51f2e9ecabe42161a4c6bf)

What functions are available in detail depends on the version. But since you said you consider switching, assuming a more recent version should be fair.