# how to split a JSON column into multiple as I showed here in Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

One of the column of my table is JSON like this:

| timestamp | values |
| --- | --- |
| xxxx | [{"d_st":1601,"d_val":2.731},{"d_st":1602,"d_val":0.465},{"d_st":1603,"d_val":0.422},{"d_st":1604,"d_val":2.803},{"d_st":1605,"d_val":2.771},{"d_st":1606,"d_val":260.352}] |

How could I split it into d_st and d_val like this:

| timestamp | dst | dval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | 1601 | 2.731 |
| xxxx | 1602 | 0.465 |
| and so on |  |  |

I used this:

```
SELECT values ->> "d_st" AS dst, values ->> 'd_val' AS val 
FROM ss;
```

but can't get any value, just two empty column, why is that?

Comment: Because `->>` does 'Extracts JSON object field with the given key, as text.' and `values` is an array of objects. See examples here [JSON functions/operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: I think you need to join your outer array, have a look at the join statement in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54337777/4083475 (I don't have postgres to test and give an actually good answer atm)

Comment: Thanks so much guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this purpose, you can use `json_to_recordset` or `jsonb_to_recordset` function depending on the data type of `values` column as follows:

```
Select ss.timestamp, x.d_st, x.d_val
From ss Cross Join Lateral json_to_recordset(ss.values) As x(d_st int, d_val numeric)
```

Result:

| timestamp | d_st | d_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | 1601 | 2.731 |
| xxxx | 1602 | 0.465 |
| xxxx | 1603 | 0.422 |
| xxxx | 1604 | 2.803 |
| xxxx | 1605 | 2.771 |
| xxxx | 1606 | 260.352 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a6868fe724a6ecf4635e4061c97c55f8)

Comment: This is really helpful! cheers bro!